# Access a Cloud-stored File using Python 3?

Tags: python, database, file, cloud, storage

I currently have a Python program which reads a local file (containing a pickled database object) and saves to that file when it's done. I'd like to branch out and use this program on multiple computers accessing the same database, but I don't want to worry about synchronizing the local database files with each other, so I've been considering cloud storage options. Does anyone know how I might store a single data file in the cloud and interact with it using Python?

I've considered something like Google Cloud Platform and similar services, but those seem to be more server-oriented whereas I just need to access a single file on my own machines.

Answer (score 0):

You could install gsutil and the boto library and use that.